# Bash autocomplete swallowing '@'

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm trying to write a bash autocomplete script to complete known ssh hostnames.

This is working well for naked hostnames (e.g. `$ ssh someh<TAB>` completes to `$ssh somehost.example.com`) but fails when using the `user@host` pattern.
In that case, the first completion works, but swallows the '@' character:

`$ ssh user@someho<TAB>`
yields
`$ ssh usersomehost.example.com`

Further completion then fails because usersomehost.example.com is now treated as one word in `$COMP_CWORDS`.

Here is the function doing the work:

```
_complete_ssh_hosts ()
{
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  comp_ssh_hosts=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=",| "} !/^[[#]|^$/ { print $1 }' ~/.ssh/known_hosts;
                   awk '/^Host.*/ { if ($2 ~ !/^\*.*/) print $2}' ~/.ssh/config)
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${comp_ssh_hosts}" -- "$cur"))
  return 0
}
```

Can anyone give me a pointer as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that `comp_ssh_hosts` is not empty? If it is, I think `compgen` is  falling back to the default completions, which attempts to expand a `@`-prefixed strings to a hostname.

Comment: You might want to look at the (extremely long) function [_known_hosts_real](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/7b9dc46c6a26a1a8e99409bb7752dfe153f2de0f/bash_completion#L1471) in the bash_completions project.

Comment: I identified that the problem is ultimately caused by the @ being in the list of word separators.
I'm not sure why it is being swallowed up in the end, but I have decided that removing and re-adding it to that list is an acceptable workaround for my use case.

Comment: @PhilTaprogge Would you mind posting your final solution as an answer please? I have the exact same issue but I'm not sure how to go about removing and re-adding `@`.